# preg_match for "^/page/(\d+)$"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This should be really simple but I'm struggling getting this preg_match to work.

I want to capture the page number from a url like this "/page/30/"
where $match[0] will return 30.

```
$uri = "/page/30/";
$pat = "/^\/page\/(\d+)$/";
preg_match($pat, $uri,$matches);
print_r($matches); //should print 30
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason, you didn't got an output is (like Greg said), you forgot the trailing slash in your pattern.

As a hint, when you want to match `/` literally, then use different regex delimiters, to avoid escaping the slashes.

So this would match your pattern:

```
$uri = "/page/30/";
$pat = "~^/page/(\d+)/$~";
preg_match($pat, $uri, $matches);
print_r($matches); //should print 30
```

Then there is a misunderstanding, `$matches` is returning an array that contains the whole match in `$matches[0]` and then the matched groups.

So if you want to print `30` you need to do:

```
print($matches[1]);
```

since the digits are stored in the first capturing group.

Answer (score 3):

```
$uri = "/page/30/";
$pat = "/(?<=^\/page\/)\d+/";
preg_match($pat, $uri, $matches);
print_r($matches); //should print 30
```

Change regex to `/(?<=^\/page\/)\d+/`. See the tutorial on [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You are disregarding the trailing slash. This should match it correctly:

```
$pat = "/^\/page\/(\d+)\/$/";
```

Comment: The problem is that the end of line character was included in the pattern, without taking into account the trailing slash. Your solution works as well, as you did not include the end of line character.